# Magento 2 validation problem (validate just the first field)

Tags: validation, form-validation

Simplify tthe code especially.
Probem: only the first elemts will be validated on submit
field-2 will be validated if I'll remove first field. Strange problem. Not depends of M2 vesion. That's phtml inclided to the CMS page

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="testform_01" class="testform">

    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="field-1">Text</label>
        <input type="text" id="field-1" data-validate='{"required":true}'/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="field-2">Text</label>
        <input type="text" id="field-2" data-validate='{"required":true}'/>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="form-submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

</form>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#testform_01": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by removing the data-validate attribute from your input fields and instead using a validation rule in your script. Here's an example:

```
   <form action="#" method="post" id="testform_01" class="testform">

        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="field-1">Text</label>
            <input type="text" id="field-1"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="field-2">Text</label>
            <input type="text" id="field-2"/>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="form-submit">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </form>

    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#testform_01": {
                "validation": {
                    "rules": {
                        "field-1": {
                            "required": true
                        },
                        "field-2": {
                            "required": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

In this example, the validation rules for each input field are specified in the "rules" object within the "validation" object. This ensures that both fields will be validated on form submission, regardless of whether one of the fields has been removed.

Also note that you can use the id attribute of the input fields to specify the validation rules for each field.

Comment: Yes, sure, the fine way. BTW, the problem of my code example was that this was a draft and I didn't use name attributies